# Can a duplex WCF channel service requests from both ends simultaneously?

Tags: .net, wcf, duplex-channel

A Client application is connecting to a Server application using a duplex WCF channel. Possible transport protocols for this channel are either Named Pipes or TCP.

The duplex channel allows the Server application to take the initiative and request an operation on the Client.

**Can this channel service requests from both ends simultaneously?**

In other words:
While the client is making use of the channel, can the server request a callback operation?

Or the other way around, can the client begin a request on the server while the channel is servicing a callback request?

Comment: Why don't you test it and see? Have the consumer call a long running operation on the service, and while it's being executed, have the server event back to the consumer. I assume that this would work, but there's only one way to find out.